# What is a good way to find research with statistics data?

Tags: data-request

I'm searching for some researches for a study project , I'm looking for some researches that contains data bases or statistics data so i can apply my project on those researches , any practical way to find researches with such things( statistics data ) ? for example i want a study that shows relation between online studying and 6 different independent variables about the people who practiced in the study ex : gender , age, etc, or any other topics..

Answer (score 1):

You can use https://www.kaggle.com/ There you have data samples and other people solving the problems with real examples of the solution in python, r or even excel. So you can track and see the logic of other people as well as try to solve the question your way. There also paid competitions... E.g. you can win up to 100k by solving some statistical question of a company... Good source to learn and research.

Comment: U can guide me more how to find a research with 6 independent values?

Answer (score 0):

One source that can be used in this directions - https://paperswithcode.com/ Caveat- Only for machine learning.
For bigger demographics you ca use RTI in india.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).